# Does referer effects GA tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, refer

I am thinking to add `Referrer-policy` header in my app. Setting this header to  :-

`Referrer-policy - origin when cross origin`
 will send only base url (http://www.example.com) in referer header to all the third parties.

Is there any chance that this might effect Google-Analytics tracking ?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Google does not use HTTP referer header field. It uses it's own [Document Referrer `dr` field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#referrer) which is initialized as:

> This field is initialized by the create command and is only set when
>   the current hostname differs from the referrer hostname, unless the
>   'alwaysSendReferrer' field is set to true.

And you may change it by: `ga('set', 'referrer', 'http://example.com')`